# Restore SQL database for WordPress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Unfortunately my VPS got corrupted and therefore I wasn't able to perform an export of the sql database with phpmyadmin. I do managed to copy all the SQL files .frm, .idb, .opt etc

Is it possible to recover the database and make my wordpress site working again?

Im using centos7 with Plesk Onyx / phpmyadmin

Comment: So you were able to backup the MySQL install folder, but not export a SQL dump from your database ? Hum... What you could try: reinstall same MySQL version, and copy/replace files. You could also research what are the exact files containing your DB data to replace only those ones.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!  First get a new instance of your VPS running and create your database again, after created copy the .idb(innodb) or .myi/.myd(mysami) files right back where you found them

Each table comes with a **.frm**, don't forget those, as well as a **db.opt** for the database

Typical mysql storage (on linux) is located:

> /var/lib/mysql/**database_name**

Once copied over restart mysql and check again